# What is the difference between a cryptocurrency, a digital currency, and a virtual currency?

Tags: currencies, digitalcoin

I'm wondering what are the differences between the three terms.

I have the impression that they are used somewhat interchangeably, with people talking about Bitcoin being the most popular "virtual currency" etc.

Some people say [virtual currency is the subset of digital currency](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/digital-vs-virtual-currencies-1408735507/), while others argue [conversely](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-cryptocurrency-a-digital-currency-and-a-virtual-currency).

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you.